# logcat file showing errors

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.ishan.complainbox;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;


public class Crime extends MainActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener,LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
private Button btnSelect;
private ImageView imgView,ivImage;
private String userChosenTask;
EditText street, city, pincode, detail;
Button btnsave;
crimeDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
        // Get References of Views
        street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.str);
        city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
        pincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pin);
        detail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.detail);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadpic);
        dbHandler = new crimeDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strt = street.getText().toString();
                String cty = city.getText().toString();
                String pin = pincode.getText().toString();
                String det = detail.getText().toString();
                Bitmap bitmap = 
  ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
                btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
                selectImage();
                dbHandler.insertEntry(strt, cty, pin, det,imageInByte);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complaint 
Successfully Filed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    }
  }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, String[] 
 permissions,
    int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (userChosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if (userChosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else
                    break;
        }
    }



  private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
 } 


  private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
           "Cancel" };
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Crime.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result=userChosenTask.checkPermission(Crime.this);
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo"))
           {
               userChosenTask ="Take Photo";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent();
            }
            else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library"))
            {
                userChosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent();
           }
            else if (items[item].equals("Cancel"))
            {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }

     });
     builder.show();
  }
  private void galleryIntent()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select 
 File"),SELECT_FILE);
 }
  private void cameraIntent()
   {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
 }

  @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
  }
   private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File destination = new 
  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),System.currentTimeMillis() 
  + ".jpg");
     FileOutputStream fo;
     try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

     ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
          bm = 
          MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap
            (getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
         }
          catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

       ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
      }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);


   }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    } 
}
```

This is one activity class of my android project and this activity depends on another utility class....which is mentioned below:

The statement `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();` shows an error in "imageView" and the statement `boolean result=userChosenTask.checkPermission(Crime.this);` shows an error on "**checkPermission**"...but I don't understand why...because checkPermission is already defined in the utility class....

```
package com.example.ishan.complainbox;

/**
 * Created by ishan on 11/04/2017. 
*/
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
 public class Utility {
 public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
 {
 int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
 if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
 Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if 
(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((MainActivity) context, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is 
necessary");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) 
context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
            alert.show();

        } else
            {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) context, 
  new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  } else
    {
    return true;
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the errors are?  Otherwise, it's really impossible to help you.  You wouldn't go to the doctor and not tell her what your symptoms are, would you?

Comment: I  have mentioned the errors in between the two code blocks

Comment: You've mentioned where the errors are, but not what the error messages say.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifests.xml, you need to include permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`